# Text processing: compare two sorted files and exclude different lines, based on second column

Tags: shell, awk, text-processing

**fileA**

```
232 com.path.class1
32  com.path.class2
123 com.path.class3
```

**fileB**

```
675 com.path.class6
567 com.path.class2
657 com.path.class1
```

noLines(fileA) > noLines(fileB)

I want to remove from fileA all lines where the column 2 (the one containing the classes) do not exists in fileB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following `awk` may help you on same.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$2];next} ($2 in a)' fileB fileA
```

In case you want to save output into Input_file fileA itself append `> temp_file && mv temp_file fileA` to above code too then.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!

Comment: @HumbleStudent, cool, glad that it helped you. Cheers and enjoy learning and sharing knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

with `join` (expects the files to be sorted; so sort)

```
$ join -j2 -o1.1,1.2 <(sort -k2 file1) <(sort -k2 file2)

232 com.path.class1
32 com.path.class2
```